# Am I exempt from taxes if I work for a college?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security, withholding

I work at an accredited community college. I ask this because my paycheck, along with several other colleagues, had 0 withholdings for state, federal, and ssn. I was told that we get tax breaks because we work for the government, but that answer seems very incorrect to me.

Comment: When you said "0 withholdings" did you mean "$0 withholdings" or "no withholdings". The latter should indicate that you are paying your maximum estimated tax obligation each pay cycle while the former would indicate that you have like 99 withholdings or something.

Comment: I meant that I have no taxes being paid. Under the state, fedearl, and ssn, sections it shows $0. My whole check is given to me without any taxes deducted.

Comment: State employees are certainly not generically exempt from federal taxes.  At least in my state, they are not exempt from state taxes either.  They *can* be exempt from social security tax, but it depends on the state.  Is it possible your pay is so low that you are in the 0% tax bracket?

Comment: State/Federal Government Employees still pay tax FYI, it is just that it might be different. i.e. military members have a certain amount of earnings untaxed if they are deployed in a combat zone.

Comment: This really sounds like someone in payroll just screwed up. Your status as a government employee, whatever it is, doesn't exempt you from all withholding if you're earning a normal income and not a grant or stipend.

Comment: Sorry for the misplaced question. I suppose it's possible my check could have been low enough in the 0% bracket but would that change as my pay increases? I'm not entirely sure what to do about it because I've always had taxes pulled from my last job, even if the pay was low.

Comment: You need to talk to someone at your college and ask to have them sort it out, and if they are being unhelpful, insist on talking to a supervisor and/or getting a _detailed_ explanation about why your taxes aren't being withheld. Strangers on the internet won't be of much help with something like this. Pro tip: be assertive and you will clear this issue up in no time (I wish I had gotten this advice 15 years ago...).

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks! You guys have been very helpful :)

Comment: Make sure you deal with this asap though, because if they just messed up and you aren't actually below the bracket (ie, they should be taking taxes out but aren't), then you might need to pay estimated quarterly taxes in advance and can get fined for not doing so. Fellowship recipients often have to deal with this and it's a pretty major and confusing pain to sort out the first time.

Comment: What type of employee are you? When I was a graduate student, some stipends did not have tax withholdings, but we still was responsible for paying taxes.

Comment: Are you a student at the college?

Answer (score 7):

Students at college employed by the college are [exempt from the FICA taxes](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/student-exception-to-fica-tax) (Social Security and Medicare).  You are not exempt from federal and state income taxes, but if you are a part time employee making a small amount of money, you probably aren't projected to be paid enough between now and the end of the year to trigger the withholding.

If you are concerned that your tax burden for the year will require you to send in money at tax time next year, you can estimate what your taxes will be, and if you determine that you will owe too much, you can fill out a new W-4 form with your HR department and request that additional tax be withheld.

Comment: Income tax withholding doesn't vary over time unless your pay _rate_ changes; it projects your pay to the full year and pro-rates the (estimated) tax on that, unless the employee qualifies for and requests part-year treatment which OP doesn't mention. If your annualized pay less probable deduction and exemptions leaves no taxable income, there is no withholding. For single with the basic 2 allowances this is up to $10,400 (for 2017); married, dependents or extra deductions all increase the amount. Otherwise concur.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've reworded slightly based on your comment.  Better?